# videos unable to be played after saving to the camera roll

Tags: react-native, react-native-camera

[ When testing with a read device this problem did not exist ]

I'm using react-native-camera

Everything works besides saving videos, they show up in the camera roll but have no thumbnail and just show the error video cannot be played. taking photos works and I can view them in the camera roll afterwards. I've made sure versioning is correct, and all the necessary permissions are there. I'm running it on an emulated android device.

[here is the takephoto.js file](https://github.com/llennox/anonshot/blob/master/src/components/TakePhoto.js)

Comment: I'm having the same issue, have you found a solution yet?

Comment: it was just the emulated android device when I tried it with a real device it never occurred